# Ui menu not working when collapsed.

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, xhtml, submenu

My collapsable menu does not link when it is collapsed in all instances including mobile devices. I am truly puzzled and cannot come out with a solution.

Here is my link:

http://torrentcreative.com/Display_1.0/index.html#

Please help.

Eddie.

Comment: try not to link to the live code, but instead a fiddle

Comment: Your bootstrap JavaScript file has an error in it! Looks like some sort of SVN merge fail.

Comment: Wow.. that was fast. Thanks Bencripps2.
How can I fix this? This is a bit over my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging your javascript:

line number 1983 in your bootstrap.js

typo here:

```
$('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>')
```

should be:

```
$('<div class="dropdown-backdrop">')
```

line number 1985:

remove curly brackets

Comment: Thanks Giri!! I revised the code. Unfortunately I tried the menu again and it is still not linking.